# Access to file is denied exception with asp.net impersonation

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, file-io, impersonation

I am trying to access the files  with following c# code, but when i try to execute the code i am encountered with exception saying access to path @"\MAHESH-PC\D$\temp\CloudURL.txt is denied .

[image]

Impersonation imp = new Impersonation("MAHESH-PC", "mahesh", "welcome");
        File.Copy(@"\MAHESH-PC\D$\temp\CloudURL.txt", @"C:\temp\CloudURL.txt", true);

I have given all the access rights to both the temp folders one in the c: drive and other in the d: drive

[image]

I have enabled the Impersonation in the IIS , even then i am getting access denied exception , please can i know is their any other settings i should implement to make this working.

[image]

Comment: try to Map Network Drive Option. Map \\MAHESH-PC to Z: Drive then try your copy things.

Comment: try changing `app pool identity` to `local system` in the `iis`

Comment: @Anand : can i have a syntax like  File.Copy(@"\\MAHESH-PC\temp\CloudURL.txt", @"\\ADMIN-PC\temp\CloudURL.txt", true); to move the files from MAHESH-PC machine to ADMIN-PC machine

Comment: @RaghuveerGuthikonda : what difference does it make if i change the app pool identity

Comment: @mahesh by using `LocalSystem`, your `iis` will have more access permissions to your computer compare to the other accounts, [link](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/60e38cf5-5ba9-4b30-a4d4-0da5976b83f3.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: @RaghuveerGuthikonda:My main theme is to transfer files between two machines within the network, do you know any good link or article which explains the whole process .

Comment: @mahesh did you check this code project article [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19830/How-to-Access-Network-Files-using-asp-net)

Comment: did you check [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887623)

Comment: @RaghuveerGuthikonda : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19830/How-to-Access-Network-Files-using-asp-net , this link explains the solution for II6 , i am looking for a article which explains using IIS7

Comment: @mahesh check [this](http://forums.asp.net/p/1348994/2765617.aspx) once

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8050/discussion-between-mahesh-and-raghuveer-guthikonda)

Answer (score 1):

Is impersonation enabled in your web.config? I'm not positive but I wouldn't think enabling impersonation in IIS has any affect on the impersonation of your site. If not, turn it on, or grant the app pool identity read/write access to both your directories and see if that helps.

Also, double check your folder system security. It appears you granted everyone read/write access to the share, but if you're navigating to the path \pc\drive$\ then it may be relying on file system security and not the security on the folder share itself. Make sense?

Comment: If i enable impersonation in the webconfig file i get the following error ,Could not create Windows user token from the credentials specified in the config file. Error from the operating system 'Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password

Comment: I have used following line of code in the webconfig file  <identity  impersonate="true" userName="admin-PC\admin" password="welcome"  />